# jQuery - "rebinding" while stopping propagation

Tags: jquery, bind

I have a situation where:

1. I add a click listener to a container
2. After a click I remove the listener so only a child can recognize a click
3. After the child is clicked the functionality of the container is restored

```
   _______________________
  | #container   [#child] |
  |_______________________|
```

My original idea:

```
var toggleContainer = function() {
   var width = ($('#container').width() > 299) ? 145 : 300;
   $('#container').animate({ width: width }).off('click');
}

$('#container').click(toggleContainer);

$('#child').click(toggleContainer, function() {
   $('#container').on('click', toggleContainer);
});
```

The functionality works except that the container click listener (toggleContainer) is never rebound. I thought the issue might be event propagation when the child is clicked, but adding event.stopPropagation() to the child breaks everything.

So I'm stumped. I'd really appreciate any advice you can offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the second function argument to the `click` method doesn't do what you think it's doing. Take a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Is http://jsfiddle.net/F9aJ4/1/ what you're trying to do?